# Can "indefinite article" in the expression "on a ... basis " be changed to a definite article?

Tags: articles, collocations, adverbial-phrases

> Salary is paid on a monthly basis.

I created the sentence above. It is assumed here that a year is divided into several periods.  For example, each period has three months, and salary is sometimes paid every three months.  In this case, can I say as follows?:

> Salary is generally paid on a monthly basis, but sometimes on the/that period basis.

I am afraid whether this is correct because I couldn't find this usage. **I want to use a period the length of which is defined myself.**

This example may be not good.  I merely want to know whether it is possible to use the form of "on the ... basis".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no requirement to use **the** merely because you're switching from a "standard" basis like weekly or monthly or quarterly to an idiosyncratic one:

> Salary is generally paid on a monthly basis, but sometimes on another basis that takes special circumstances into account.

If you have  given a *name* to that special basis earlier in the document, let's say you had called it the "Rama" basis, you could use either article:

> Salary is generally paid on a monthly basis, but sometimes on a|the Rama basis.

It is difficult to answer such questions in the abstract.  It really depends on how you refer to this custom or idiosyncratic basis in your text.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to stick with *a ____ly basis*. Using *the* in this context is rare and thus reserved for contexts that are specialized or have been used since the 1950s.

So, you will want to say/write

> Salary is generally paid on **a monthly basis**, but sometimes on **a quarterly basis**.

Note that *quarterly* is the time period that amounts to every three months, or four times a year.

Depending on which corpora of English one searches, there is either no or an extremely (actually, abysmally) low number of uses of *the* before a string such as *daily/weekly/monthly/quarterly/yearly basis*.

Even Google Ngrams [gives this result](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+monthly+basis%2Cthe+monthly+basis%2Ca+weekly+basis%2Cthe+weekly+basis&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20monthly%20basis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20monthly%20basis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20weekly%20basis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20weekly%20basis%3B%2Cc0).

[image]

Comment: I want to use a period the length of which is defined myself.